# riseOnHover property is not working in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, hover

I'm creating a map using leaflet js, which has several markers.

The question is, how can I get riseOnHover property to work?

As mentioned in [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-riseonhover):

> If true, the marker will get on top of others when you hover the mouse
> over it.

So I got a simple code like:

```
let map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
let tile = L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    noWrap: true,
});

tile.addTo(map);



let options = {
    riseOnHover: true,
};
let marker = L.marker([0, 0], options);
marker.addTo(map);
```

But nothing happens. I also tried it with serveral markers at once, in case maybe there should be more than one marker to get riseOnHover to work, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Unfortunately, the docs explain riseOnHover property in a way which the reader thinks it is used to rise markers a little in y axis, but in real use, it increases the z-index of the marker which we are hovering.

It will work well if you have several markers which are overlapping each other. Just hover on one of them and you see the magic!